# Haxe becomes unable to compile after a system restart

Tags: haxe

The problem is, after I've installed Haxe, I can compile a simple program. But after a system restart, I turn on my computer again and I try to compile the same untouched code, it won't compile.

The error is this:

```
[Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[cmd:  [u'haxelib', u'run', u'openfl', u'test', u'project.xml', u'neko', u'-debug']]
[dir:  C:\Users\&&&&&&&\Desktop\haxeproj\exampleHaxe]
[path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;%HAXEPATH%;%NEKO_INSTPATH%;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin; ]
[Finished]
```

I also have to mention that when I run any of the haxe/haxelib/openfl/lime commands on the console, it tells me that it's an unknown command.

I use Sublime Text 2.

Really need help fixing this, I really hope I don't end up needing to reinstall Haxe everytime I restart my computer just to be able to work on by project. Thanks!

Comment: Tell us how do you install haxe (using official installer or what). What version of haxe you've installed (3.2.0?). What OS you're using (I guess it is Windows from looking at the paths)? General debug procedure: check `haxe` can be run in a command prompt. if so, run `where haxe` to print its location.

Comment: So here's everything, 
I installed Haxe from the official installer, on version 3.2.0.
Running on windows 8.1, both the computer that works and the one that doesn't are running on 8.1.
I've checked via command prompt, and as stated in the post, all commands have returned unknown command until I've reinstalled Haxe using the same method every time.

After reinstalling, it works, and after running **where haxe**, it returned "C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\haxe.exe", as it is expected to be. It is and has always been in that location.

Comment: Check the PATH env variable, when it works, and when it doesn't work. Sounds like it is overwritten everytime you restart the computer.

Comment: Yes, I checked the path env variable immediately after I realized that the program was not compiling correctly. But It seemed that the paths were set correctly. The variable %HAXEPATH% to the haxe folder, and %NEKO_INSTPATH% to the neko folder, then under PATH, these 2 variables were defined. I have also tried using the actual path itself, rather than using the variables names.

Comment: Of course, running the command prompt directly from C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe allowed me to run haxe.exe, but running haxelib.exe gave me an error, because neko.exe could not be found. So seeing that, I ran the command prompt one level up, inside the HaxeToolkit folder, and I could run neither haxe.exe nor neko.exe, or any of the exes related to haxe.

Comment: Just double check: when it doesn't work, running `echo %PATH%` in command prompt still prints a string that includes "C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\"?

Comment: Alright, so I've had it working since I had to do some writing, but I still think it's going to be a recurring problem, so just tried to recreate the situation by restarting the machine. But now it runs fine, and I immediately booted up cmd and tested the haxe command and every other haxe related command once the computer started up, and they seem to be working. But I really don't trust this one bit. This is quite weird.

Comment: Does that issue still happen to you?

Comment: No, it does not seem to happen to me anymore. Thank you.